# Can Piwik report referrer in real time?

Tags: javascript, analytics, referrer, matomo

I am looking to query Piwik API in real-time to get stats on the *current* visitor. For example, I have a javascript file that'd I'd like to fetch Piwik API JSON with to get info on the visitor who is using the page which contains the javascript file (referrer, mobile/desktop, location etc.)

As far as I understand Piwik must have this data to generate analytics on per-user basis. My fear is that it might not actually allow querying this info in the way I've described above. If that's the case, what can I do to obtain it from PW? Obviously API method would be better, but if not I'd like to use the same system to make real-time reports as the one I use to generate stats on the groups of the users this particular one belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [API page](http://piwik.org/docs/real-time/#real-time-analytics-api), the PIWIK Live! widget refreshes every 5 seconds, and displays new visits. For each visitor, you can see:

- date
- number of actions
- time spent on the site
- country
- browser
- operating system
- whether the visitor is new or a returning visit
- the **referrer** used to access your site (Search engine & keyword, Campaign,
  or Referrer website)
- whether the visitor converted a goal

You can query the [Live! API Module](http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/reporting-api) and the use the  **Live.getLastVisitsDetails** method to get the data you asked about.